# How to write Test case for Internal functions in solidity which inherits the ERC721

Tags: truffle, blockchain, ethereumjs, mocha, solidity-0.8.x

**This is my Smart Contract code which has  inherited the ERC721 and I want to write the test case for _setTokenURI **

```
 contract ProductNFT is ERC721 { 
        constructor () public ERC721(_tokenName,_tokenSymbol) { }
        function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) internal  virtual {
            require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI set of nonexistent token");  
             changed");
            _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
            emit setTokenURI (tokenId, _tokenURI);
      
        }
  

  }
```

**As the function _setTokenURI is an Internal so I inherited the contract productNFt in another file **

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./mycode.sol";



contract ProductNFTTest is ProductNFT {

    constructor () public  ProductNFT () {

    }

    event setTokenURI_ (uint tk_id, string tk_URI);

    function testSetTokenURI (uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI ) external  {

        
        _setTokenURI(tokenId,_tokenURI);
        emit setTokenURI_ (tokenId,_tokenURI);

 

       }
    }
```

> _exists function comes from the [_exists function detail](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol)
> **How to write the test case for _setTokenURI I have tried but I am unable to fullfill the required statement **

```
const { assert } = require('chai');
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
const ProductNFTTest = artifacts.require('ProductNFTTest');
require('chai')
    .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
    .should()

contract('ProductNFTTest', (accounts) => {
    let contract_ProductNFTTest 
    let owner = accounts[0]
    let account_brandwallet = accounts[1]
    let designer_address = accounts[2]
    
    before(async ()=> {
        console.log("Bye--------------")
        contract_ProductNFTTest  = await ProductNFTTest.deployed() 
        console.log('ABI....of contract_ProductNFTTest....',contract_ProductNFTTest)
    })
    
    describe('deployment', async() => {
        it('deploys successfully', async()=> {
            const address = contract_ProductNFTTest.address
            assert.notEqual(address,'')
            assert.notEqual(address,0x0)
            assert.notEqual(address,null)
            assert.notEqual(address,undefined)
            assert.ok(address)

        })
    
    })

    describe('_setTokenURI', async() => {
        it('sets token URI ', async() => {
            const result = await contract_ProductNFTTest.testSetTokenURI(1,'www.example.com');
        })
    })

})
```

**I am getting an error Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC721Metadata: URI set of nonexistent token -- Reason given: ERC721Metadata: URI set of nonexistent token as I am not checking the required statement in my code**